# why Apache Camel file to sftp route fails

Tags: java, file, apache-camel, sftp

*I am new to Camel*.

I read the basics and managed to do simple file to file route. When I tried from file to sftp. It failed.

For testing, I have windows 10 as host os and mint Linux as guest os. I can access from win to linux by sftp client. So I have no issue with the access between host an guest. I tried the following code:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
        try {
            camelContext.addRoutes(new FtpRouteBuilder());
            camelContext.start();
            Thread.sleep(200000);
            // do other stuff...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.printf("ex: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            camelContext.stop();
        }
    }
}

public class FtpRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        try {
            from("file:c:/temp/input/")
                    .to("sftp://sftpuser@192.168.10.54/?password=dev&passiveMode=true");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.printf("ex: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

}

When I tried this code. I got the following exception:-

> ```
>   Failed to create route route1 at: >>>
>   To[sftp://sftpuser@192.168.10.54/?password=dev&passiveMode=true] <<<
>   in route: Route(route1)[[From[file:c:/temp/input/]] ->
>   [To[sftp://sftp... because of Failed to resolve endpoint:
>   sftp://sftpuser@192.168.10.54/?passiveMode=true&password=dev due to:
>   No component found with scheme: sftp18/11/24 17:50:30 INFO
>   impl.DefaultCamelContext: Apache Camel 2.15.1 (CamelContext: camel-1)
>   uptime 0.296 seconds
> ```

What is wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Seems that you're missing the ftp libraries (`camel-ftp`). Check the component's page to see what dependency to add: http://people.apache.org/~dkulp/camel/ftp2.html

Comment: Thanks, could you pls check my answer and tell me how to fix the warning.

Comment: Check the javadocs here: https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/RuntimeConfiguration.html#setAllowUseOriginalMessage(java.lang.Boolean) . It seems that it's a flag you set on your camel context. If you have a different error following this, please post it on a different question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to ernest_k for pointing out the missing library. I added:-

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
   <artifactId>camel-ftp</artifactId>
   <version>2.15.1</version>
</dependency>

public class FtpRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        try{
            from("file:c:/temp/input/")
                    ..streamCaching()
                    .to("sftp://sftpuser@192.168.10.54:/sftpuser/?password=dev");
        }catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.printf("ex: "+ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

It is fixed and the main point to note that the sftp URI. It works.